# how to tell prolog to use `is` instead of `=` for matching predicates

Tags: prolog

I am trying to implement some basics of tic tac toe. I am struggling with a predicate that would tell if something is a line of 'x', given start of line, direction and length.

```
is_x((0, 0)). is_x((1, 0)). is_x((2, 0)).
              is_y((1, 1)).
is_y((0, 2)).

is_empty(P) :- \+is_x(P), \+is_y(P).

is_line_of_x(Start, _, 1) :- is_x(Start).
is_line_of_x((StartX, StartY), (DirX, DirY), Length) :-
    is_x((StartX, StartY)),
    is_line_of_x((StartX + DirX, StartY + DirY), (DirX, DirY), Length - 1).
```

I expected `is_line_of_x((0, 0), (1, 0), 3)` to be `true`, however it is not. I tried to kind of debug it manually from repl, I noticed that

```
?- is_line_of_x((1, 0), (1, 0), 1).
true .
```

but

```
?- is_line_of_x((0 + 1, 0 + 0), (1, 0), 1).
false.
```

So `(0 + 1, 0 + 0)` and `(1, 0)` are not equivalent. How can I work around that?

Sorry if the title is misleading, I couldn't figure anything better.

### Edit

```
is_line_of_x(Start, _, 1) :- is_x(Start).
is_line_of_x((StartX, StartY), (DirX, DirY), Length) :-
    is_x((StartX, StartY)),
    NextX is StartX + DirX,
    NextY is StartY + DirY,
    is_line_of_x((NextX, NextY), (DirX, DirY), Length - 1).
```

I tried to use `is` like this, but it didn't help, `is_line_of_x((0, 0), (1, 0), 3)` still yields `false`.

Comment: You need to use `is/2`: `X is 0+1, Y is 0+0, is_line_of_x((X,Y), (1,0),1).`

Comment: See: [is/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2)

Comment: Thanks, but what I did in repl was just a test to see why I have a problem. However the real problem is that I want this predicate to work, I tried to use `is` but it didn't help. Can you see my edit?

Comment: You should also consider that pattern matching is one of Prolog's greatest strengths and that you should consider using that. If you want to do it with a math basis in Prolog then consider using [Constraint Satisfaction](CLP(FD) Constraint Logic Programming over Finite Domains)

Comment: I find it rather weird that you code the board as a set of facts. In a tictactoe game, the board changes, whereas facts in Prolog are not time sensitive (yes, there is the `assert/1` predicate, etc. to add/remove facts), but these are usually anti-patterns.

Comment: Of interest: [A Tic-Tac-Toe program in Prolog](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/03sp/slides/PrologEx/tictactoe.pl.txt) Uses pattern matching.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I plan to call feed prolog with current state of board and ask it for next move, rest of game will be in different language.

Comment: @Guy Coder, thanks but I actually want to have infinite board and line of 5 to win, so it is not strictly tic tac toe.